# Excel formula to search duplicate values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large set of invoices, with a lot of duplicate information. Each one of my invoices has sub orders, and they all have different prices associated with them. In my data the invoices just appear multiple times (instead of the order numbers appearing) but the numbers price column is changing - there is no unique identifier.

I'm trying to pull the various prices using vlookup into a new sheet, but when I do this I keep getting the first price for each of my invoices. Any ideas what I could do instead? I tried using an Index Match but kept getting errors. And I cant insert any new 'helper' columns either!

Comment: While there are array formulas that will do this, the best would be filter and copy or advanced filter.  You can use vba to do these steps automatically.  The shear number of Array formula to do what you want will cause the calcs to crawl.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for a data set in colomn A from cell A2 till the end

```
Sub RemoveDup()
    Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that you have sub orders against your invoices. There can be two possibilities

1. Get total of all sub orders.
2. Get amounts per sub order.

The first one is simple you can do that using sumif() against a unique list of invoices

For second one you have to insert a sub order column and fill it with a counter to indicate each order, after that you can use a pivot table to get individual amount per sub order as well as the total amount per invoice.

If you can show a screenshot of your sheet, i can better recommend the formulae for your sheet.